# "Variable" does not exist in current context

Tags: c#, xaml

Very new to C# and programming in general. I've run into this problem and I don't really know how to solve it. First of all, here's the code :

It says in the "if" parts of the code that random1 does not exist in the current context. Yes, I am aware that random only exists within the Button_click part because it is between brackets. The code is supposed to pick a random number between 0 and 20 without displaying it so that the user has to guess it. If the user is wrong, it shows a hint saying if the number is too high or too low. How can I fix this problem? Thanks

EDIT : It seems that I was too vague, your answers were good though. This is the full code :

```
public void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) //random
{
    Random chiffrealeatoire = new Random();
    int random1 = (chiffrealeatoire.Next(0, 20));
}

private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) //quit
{
    Application.Current.Shutdown();
}

private void Button_Click_2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) //veri
{

}

public void TextBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (BoiteChiffre.Text < random1)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Too low");
    }
    if (BoiteChiffre.Text > random1)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Too high");
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Congratulations");          
    }
}
```

The user is supposed to write in the textbox

Comment: Your if & else statements are outside of a method definition. This code shouldn't compile.

Comment: You need to relocate your closing brace so that all the code is within the "Button_Click" method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've closed off your method and left out the if statement! The `random1` variable is defined and declared within your method so it doesn't exist outside of it. Please move the method's closing bracket to include the if statement as well.

Also, your two `if` statements should really be linked together with an else if. You've declared two separate if statements so only one of them will have the else. Not wrong, just better practice to the following.

Basic structure:

```
public void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {

    ...
    int random1

    if(<random1) {
        random1
    } else if(>random1) {
        ...
    } else {
        ...
    }

} // <- method closing bracket
```

Edit: Since you've heavily modified the code provided I'll have to update my explanation.

Your issue has to do with variable scope. A variable defined within a method has local scope to that method. It's not accessible and doesn't even exist outside of it. You should be declaring your method OUTSIDE all the methods so that you can have multiple methods using it.

Basic structure:

```
int random1

public void methodA() {
    random1 = whatever
}

public void methodB() {
    if(random1) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below code snippet. You need to declare the variable inside of the same method.

```
public void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) //random
{
    Random chiffrealeatoire = new Random();
    int random1 = (chiffrealeatoire.Next(0, 20));

    if (BoiteChiffre.Text < random1)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Too low");
    }
    if (BoiteChiffre.Text > random1)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Too high");
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Congratulations");          
    }
}
```